# Adapting a template with a non-type parameter as a template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template which can be reduced to the following

```
template <typename T, template <typename U> class Base>
class Derived: Base<T> {
};
```

As `Base` I would like to be able to use a template which may have a non-template parameter. For example

```
template <unsigned N, typename T>
struct NBase {
};
```

This obviously won't work directly as its parameters do not match the single parameter of `Base`, so I thought I would do something like

```
template <unsigned S>
struct NAdapter {

   template <typename T>
   using B = NBase<S, T>;
};
```

This kind of works, for instance this compiles:

```
void f() {
   Derived<int, NAdapter<100>::B> a;
}
```

This however doesn't compile

```
template <unsigned M>
void eval() {
  Derived<int, NAdapter<M>::B> b;
}
```

The resulting error is `note:   expected a class template, got ‘NAdapter<M>::B’`.

Is there a way to adapt `NBase` as `Base` so it would work in both cases?

**Solution**

This works, thank you @mutableVoid for your suggestion!

```
template <unsigned M>
void eval() {
  Derived<int, NAdapter<M>::template B> b;
}
```

Comment: check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords): from looking at it, it seems to me that you have to add 'template' in front of NAdapter<M>::B

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, now the error is "expected a class template, got ‘typename NAdapter<M>::B’"

Comment: [Works for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yZQSh8hmFbIHJAGA) Edit: I miswrote in my original comment, template has to be placed in front of B

Comment: It does indeed work, thank you very much!

Comment: Don’t edit answers into your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is [core issue 1478](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1478); some implementations require `::template` here, as pointed out in the comments.  The most [current plan](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1787r3.html) (mine) is to require this case to work without `template` and to deprecate its unnecessary use (at variance with its **parsing** purpose) there.  It may be some time before implementations follow that rule, since it hasn’t even been reviewed yet.